# Incorrectly declined flag

Tags: discussion

I flagged [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/728606/is-dota2-playable-on-the-specs-below/780946#780946) as "Low quality + not an answer"

However, it was denied (huh?)

The comment was:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to
> support it

## Huh?

Comment: Please don't use custom flags if you are just going to say what another flag already does. Custom flags are for things that need special explaining. If a post meets multiple flag criteria just pick the most obvious one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> I flagged this post as "Low quality + not an answer"

It is technically an answer, you must flag for the correct reason.

I think we all have had this one before.

Comment: IMO it's a comment.

Comment: Why? It does attempt to answer the question, it would be better as a comment but it does attempt to answer the question. The reason is "Not an answer" not "This should be a comment", answers don't have to be long, they have to attempt to answer the question. In the case you think it is a comment, use your votes to express your opinion and give feedback. Did you not get a comment from the mod on the declined flag, something like "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer"?

Comment: I put the mod's comment in my question.

Comment: And it's very low quality because the OP **can't** try it to find out. He's getting an Open GL error.

Comment: Sorry, I have not seen one in a while, I thought that was just the generic reason and the comment followed but my point still stands, they found no evidence it was not an answer because it is. That is not what the mods review, I think, though I am not 100%, the "not an answer" and others go to a mod or 20k user for review by one of them but "Low quality" goes to the review queue only. So the mod only reviewed "not an answer" part and not the other, so found no evidence to support it.

Comment: I left a custom comment, so I think the mod reviewed both.

Comment: So you flagged one answer three times? Why would you do this?

Comment: Mark is correct. "can't do it" is a valid answer. Especially when the question is "can I do it?". If it's low quality then downvote+comment, that's not what flags are for (even the low quality one, if you read its text).

Comment: @AndroidDev There are 0 comments, deleted or otherwise, on that answer..

Comment: @Seth - I mean I used a custom flag, sorry :)

Comment: @MarkKirby - No, I left **one** custom flag (not comment, sorry)

Answer (score 2):

A moderator saw your flag and disagreed. If you thought it wasn't an answer, you can probably read that to mean they did.

This answer sits on the line. It could certainly be better (cite published minimum requirements, benchmarks, etc) but it does offer an answer nonetheless.

I've seen your comments on the other answer here. If you think the situation is that complicated, use a custom flag and explain it to the mods.

Comment: That's what I did.

Comment: I mean, to be more explicit. Your message is just as brief as any of the existing flag messages. Explain yourself when you can.

Comment: That's not too say a mod will always agree. But they won't if they don't understand what you're complaining about.